# Is there an alternative to if statements?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, logic, dry

I'm making a password generator with JavaScript and it works by getting a number from an input and it generates a password with the length that it got from the input. I added three checkboxes in HTML which represent caps, numbers and symbols. If you leave the checkboxes unchecked, it will generate the password using only lowercase letters, but if you mark the caps checkbox, it will use both lowercase and uppercase letters to create the password and it works the same way with the other checkboxes.

To evaluate which checkboxes were checked I had to use plenty of if statements, here is my code:

```
if (document.getElementById('caps').checked === true && 
        document.getElementById('numbers').checked === false && 
        document.getElementById('symbols').checked === false) 
    {
        const charsArray = lowercase.concat(caps);
        
        password = GeneratePassword(passwordLength, charsArray);
    } 
    else if (document.getElementById('caps').checked === false && 
            document.getElementById('numbers').checked === true && 
            document.getElementById('symbols').checked === false)
    {
        const charsArray = lowercase.concat(numbers);

        password = GeneratePassword(passwordLength, charsArray);
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('caps').checked === false && 
            document.getElementById('numbers').checked === false && 
            document.getElementById('symbols').checked === true)
    {
        const charsArray = lowercase.concat(symbols);

        password = GeneratePassword(passwordLength, charsArray);
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('caps').checked === true && 
            document.getElementById('numbers').checked === true && 
            document.getElementById('symbols').checked === false)
    {
        const charsArray = lowercase.concat(caps).concat(numbers);

        password = GeneratePassword(passwordLength, charsArray);
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('caps').checked === true && 
            document.getElementById('numbers').checked === true && 
            document.getElementById('symbols').checked === true)
    {
        const charsArray = lowercase.concat(caps).concat(numbers).concat(symbols);

        password = GeneratePassword(passwordLength, charsArray);
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('caps').checked === false && 
            document.getElementById('numbers').checked === true && 
            document.getElementById('symbols').checked === true)
    {
        const charsArray = lowercase.concat(numbers).concat(symbols);

        password = GeneratePassword(passwordLength, charsArray);
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('caps').checked === true && 
            document.getElementById('numbers').checked === false && 
            document.getElementById('symbols').checked === true)
    {
        const charsArray = lowercase.concat(caps).concat(symbols);

        password = GeneratePassword(passwordLength, charsArray);
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('caps').checked === true && 
            document.getElementById('numbers').checked === true && 
            document.getElementById('symbols').checked === false)
    {
        const charsArray = lowercase.concat(caps);

        password = GeneratePassword(passwordLength, charsArray);
    }
    else {
        password = GeneratePassword(passwordLength, lowercase);
    }
```

As you can see, it is very repetitive. I know that one of the fundamentals for writing good code is DRY, so I wanted to know if there is another way to do this without making it so repetitive. I know switch is an alternative to if statements but I think that wouldn't solve the repetitive issue.

If anybody can provide any help I will appreciate it very much :)

Comment: You just have three conditions. So you need three `if`s - one for caps, one for numbers, one for symbols. Each should append to the available characters you have.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 boolean conditions, which indeed results in 9 different ways of generating the password. In your case though, you can change your logic into something like this:

```js
// Copy the lowercase characters
const chars = [...lowercase];

// Add to chars depending on the three conditions
if (useCaps) chars.push(...caps);
if (useNumbers) chars.push(...numbers);
if (useSymbols) chars.push(...symbols);

const password = GeneratePassword(passwordLength, chars);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don´t need to check each possibility, just check each checkbox separately using simple `if` statement (not `if-else`). Only use `lowercase` to reassigne concated values:

```
if (document.getElementById('caps').checked === true){
    lowercase= lowercase.concat(caps);
} 
if (document.getElementById('numbers').checked === true)
{
    lowercase= lowercase.concat(numbers);
}
if (document.getElementById('symbols').checked === true)
{
    lowercase= lowercase.concat(symbols);
}

password = GeneratePassword(passwordLength, lowercase);
```

A shorter way to write it is to erase the brackets `{}` and erase the `=== true` and it would still work:

```
if (document.getElementById('caps').checked)
    lowercase= lowercase.concat(caps);
if (document.getElementById('numbers').checked)
    lowercase= lowercase.concat(numbers);
if (document.getElementById('symbols').checked)
    lowercase= lowercase.concat(symbols);


password = GeneratePassword(passwordLength, lowercase);
```

And even a shorter way to write it and to avoid using `if` statements, is just using js inline conditional, similarly to a ternary operator, but it hasn't got three statements:

```
document.getElementById('caps').checked && lowercase= lowercase.concat(caps);
document.getElementById('numbers').checked && lowercase= lowercase.concat(numbers);
document.getElementById('symbols').checked && lowercase = lowercase.concat(symbols);

password = GeneratePassword(passwordLength, lowercase);
```

What it does is to check the first condition `document.getElementById('symbols').checked`. It would return `true` if is checked and `false` if it is unchecked.

- If it´s checked (`true`), it goes to the second inline condition `lowercase= lowercase.concat(caps)`. Since it is also an instruction, the code would execute the instruction.
- If it´s unchecked (`false`), code would go to the other line and do the same with that inline condition.

Comment: I would use: `lowercase = [...lowercase, ...caps]` assuming that `lowercase` was defined as a `let`.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I don't see any real difference.

Answer (score 1):

You should build an alphabet string and then access charcters at a random index.

```js
const UPPER = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const LOWER = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const NUMBERS = '0123456789';
const SYMBOLS = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^`_{|}~';

const defaultOptions = {
  includeUpper: true,
  includeLower: true,
  includeNumbers: true,
  includeSymbols: false
};

const randomInt = (min, max) => {
  if (max === undefined) {  max = min; min = 0; }
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

const randomChar = (str) => str[randomInt(str.length)];

const generatePassword = (length, options) => {
  const opts = { ...defaultOptions, ...options };
  let alphabet = '';
  
  if (opts.includeUpper) alphabet += UPPER;
  if (opts.includeLower) alphabet += LOWER;
  if (opts.includeNumbers) alphabet += NUMBERS;
  if (opts.includeSymbols) alphabet += SYMBOLS;
      
  return new Array(length).fill(0).map(() => randomChar(alphabet)).join('');
};

// Event handler
const handleSubmission = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { target: { elements } } = e;
  const generatedPassword = generatePassword(
    +elements.size.value,
    {
      includeUpper: elements.upper.checked,
      includeLower: elements.lower.checked,
      includeNumbers: elements.numbers.checked,
      includeSymbols: elements.symbols.checked
    }
  );
  document.querySelector('#generated').value = generatedPassword;
};

// UI
document.forms['password-generator'].addEventListener('submit', handleSubmission);
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: #222;
  color: #EEE;
  font-size: smaller;
}

form input[type="number"] {
  width: 3em;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.bordered {
  border: thin solid #666;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #444;
}

.vertical-form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 0.25em;
}

#generated {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<form class="bordered vertical-form" name="password-generator">
  <label>Length <input type="number" name="size" value="12" /></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="upper" checked> Uppercase</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="lower" checked> Lowercase</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="numbers"> Numbers</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="symbols"> Symbols</label>
  <button type="submit">Generate Password</button>
</form>
<label>Generated password <input type="text" id="generated" /></label>
```

Comment: I think something really similar, I just used arrays instead of strings. My question was not about that but thanks tho.

Answer (score -1):

You can always use multiple nested ternary operators if you can maintain the indentation properly.